# Does the decimal scale value replace rounding in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, decimal, rounding, scale

Considering this code:

```
DECLARE @Price AS DECIMAL(25,10) = 1231234.9898989142

DECLARE @TABLE AS TABLE 
                  (
                        Number DECIMAL(19,4)
                  )

INSERT INTO @TABLE 
VALUES (@Price)

SELECT * 
FROM @TABLE

SELECT ROUND(@Price, 4)
```

Can we count on the column decimal scale value to always round the number or should we use the `ROUND()` function to round the number before inserting into the table?

Comment: If you are looking for 1231234.9898 as answer, try this -
SELECT cast(round(@Price,4,1) as decimal(19,4))

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers, what i mean exactly, why use Round() while the column type take care of this for you.

Comment: @PierreYounes Have you visited the link?

Comment: @GSerg Yes i did, Thanks